# Multiple joins to create a cross tab

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two queries I want to join so I can get the percentages from each department of completed work orders but not sure how to go about it. I know I want a join and a crosstab query so I can display the results in a report.
The first query calculates the numerator,

```
SELECT 
    Count(MaximoReport.WorkOrder) AS CountOfWorkOrder, 
    MaximoReport.[Assigned Owner Group]
FROM MaximoReport
WHERE (
    ((MaximoReport.WorkType) In ("PMINS","PMOR","PMPDM","PMREG","PMRT")) 
    AND ((MaximoReport.Status) Like "*COMP") 
    AND ((MaximoReport.[Target Start])>=DateAdd("h",-1,[Enter the start date])
    AND (MaximoReport.[Target Start])<DateAdd("h",23,[Enter the end date])) 
    AND ((MaximoReport.ActualLaborHours)<>"00:00") 
    AND ((MaximoReport.ActualStartDate)>=DateAdd("h",-11.8,[Enter the start date]) 
    AND (MaximoReport.ActualStartDate)<DateAdd("h",23,[Enter the end date]))
)
GROUP BY MaximoReport.[Assigned Owner Group];
```

While the second query calculates the denominator:

```
SELECT 
    Count(MaximoReport.WorkOrder) AS CountOfWorkOrder, 
    MaximoReport.[Assigned Owner Group]
FROM MaximoReport
WHERE (
    ((MaximoReport.WorkType) In ("PMINS","PMOR","PMPDM","PMREG","PMRT")) 
    AND ((MaximoReport.Status)<>"CAN") 
    AND ((MaximoReport.[Target Start])>=DateAdd("h",-11.8,[Enter the start date]) 
    AND (MaximoReport.[Target Start])<DateAdd("h",23,[Enter the end date])))
GROUP BY MaximoReport.[Assigned Owner Group];
```

Please advise how I can join the two queries to get the percentages of the departments and then do a crosstab query.

If there is a better way of doing this please also let me know.

Comment: Edit question to post sample raw data and desired output. Post as text formatted to table, not images.

Comment: You will have to join both queries on the `[Assigned Owner Group]` column (the "department"?), output that column and a calculated column where you divide the two `CountOfWorkOrder` columns. That will give you a query with two columns, and I don't see a useful application of a crosstab query there.